# How to avoid multiple Arc::clone when dealing with multiple closures?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, closures

```
    let store = Arc::new(DashMap::new());
    tokio::spawn({
        let store = Arc::clone(&store);
        async move {
            stream::iter(vec![17, 19]).for_each(move |x| {
                let store = Arc::clone(&store);
                async move {
                    store.insert(x, x);
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

I have to clone two times and do it behind `async` blocks just to have an ability to use it once deep in the closures.
Are there any ways to simplify such code?

Comment: In your code, it looks like you don't need to place `store.insert(x, x);` within the second `async move` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just leave them out, the only necessary clone is the one inside of `iter` because each iteration needs it's own `Arc`.

This works unless there is some requirements not mentioned in the question.

```rust
    let store = Arc::new(DashMap::new());
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        stream::iter(vec![17, 19]).for_each(move |x| {
            let store = Arc::clone(&store);
            async move {
                store.insert(x, x);
            }
        })
    });
```

If you can move the insert outside of the innermost `async move` block you can get rid of even that clone.